# Bash Script to loop docker ps command to stop and remove old containers

Tags: bash, docker

I have a process  - in Jenkins - that create jobs with the following pattener:

> product_YYYYMMDD-HHHH

where YYYYMMDD = Year/Month/Day ; HHHH: hour. Both based in when the container was created. For example:

`jack_20181217-1457
 jack_20181218-0831`

Problem is that I need to create some bash script to check all running containers and remove the old containers for a product every week, so I start to do it getting the containers names using:

```
docker ps --format "table {{.Names}}" | tail -n +2 | sort
```

and the idea is loop the return and start to compare the dates and hour.

My question is: is there any better approach to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `format` option:

```
docker ps --format '{{.Names}}' | sort
```

There is no need to use `tail` since it gives only docker container names.

Comment: the tail is to remove the header

Comment: There won't be any header in `docker ps --format '{{.Names}}'` output